# $\{f \in C[a,b]:\forall x \in [a,b].|f(x)|\leq 1\} \subseteq C[a,b]$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> Show that the set $$\{f \in C[a,b]:\forall x \in [a,b].|f(x)|\leq 1\}
>  \subseteq C[a,b]$$ is convex.

I have done this:

If $f_1,f_2$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$ such that $\forall x \in [a,b]$, $|f(x)|\leq 1$.  I have to show that $\alpha f_1 + (1-\alpha )f_2$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\forall x \in [a,b]$, $$|\alpha f_1 (x) + (1-\alpha )f_2 (x)|\leq 1.$$

Since $f_1,f_2$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$, we have that their linear combination is continuous on $[a,b]$. Also, given $x \in [a,b]$:

$$|\alpha f_1 (x) + (1-\alpha )f_2 (x)|\leq |\alpha f_1 (x)|+|(1-\alpha )f_2 (x)|\\
= \alpha |f_1 (x)|+(1-\alpha )|f_2 (x)| \leq \alpha + (1-\alpha)=1.$$

Is this all I had to show?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: "When it goes easy, it probably goes wrong" :D So, this time it's not wrong? :)

Answer (score 2):

So this question doesn't look unanswered: Yep, it looks good!

The only thing I would add is stylistic: instead of writing $\alpha f_1+(1-\alpha)f_2$, you could write $\alpha f_1+\beta f_2$ where $\alpha+\beta=1$. This would make the algebra a little easier to read, and it would look more symmetric. Just an opinion!